# GoogleDrive::Error (Updating cell has failed: Missing resource version ID) (Rails 3 / gem 'google_drive')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm getting this error lately :

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7609ms

GoogleDrive::Error (Updating cell https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/.../od6/private/full/R1C1 has failed: Missing resource version ID)
```

I haven't change anything, it worked fine before.

Using: `Rails 3, gem 'google_drive'`

Code:

```
  def google_report
    session = GoogleDrive.login(current_user.gmail, ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(SECRET).decrypt(current_user.gmail_pass))
    asin = params[:asin]
      @i_all = Item.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :asin => asin, :domain => params[:domain]).order("created_at desc")
      # + 9 hours cuz of server time
      time = (Time.now + 9.hours).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
      session.create_spreadsheet(asin + " " + time)
      ws = session.spreadsheet_by_title(asin + " " + time).worksheets[0]
    ws[1, 1] = "商品名"
    ws[1, 2] = "ASIN"
    ...

    @i_all.try(:each_with_index) do |i, index|
      ws[index+2, 1] = i.title
      ws[index+2, 2] = i.asin
      ...

      begin
      ws.save()
      rescue GoogleDrive::Error
        ws.save()
        next
      end

    end
    ws.save()
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the gem did the trick :)

From `google_drive (0.3.7)` to `google_drive (0.3.9)`

Answer (score 1):

I think the fix was to add a version

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#specifying_a_version

I think it was optional, but they made it required.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I didn't know how to add a version in code :) so I found another solution. Nevertheless, thank you for your help.